# rhandsontable dropdown menu hidden in short data frame

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, rhandsontable

I am using `rhandsontable` with `shiny` to do a registration form with drop-down menus in order to limit answer to a list of possibilities, as the following example.

```
df <- data.frame(letters= factor(letters[1], levels=letters[1:10]),
                 LETTERS= factor(letters[2], levels=LETTERS[1:10]),
                 Name= "",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rhandsontable(df, useTypes = TRUE, width = 800)
```

This written code do not allow to see the drop-down menu ... It only shows up if I fix, for example, `height = 150` in the `rhandsontable` function. My problem is that my form consist in one-line data frames ... and It is really ugly and not functional to let big white spaces under every data frame !

If somebody has a clue or a solution, please help me if you can, I'm feeling down :)

Comment: ok I have just figure that I have to put `overflow = "visible"` without giving any height and it works.

Comment: Hey got the same trouble here where do you put the `overflow = "visible"` stuff please? Because it didn't change a think within the `rhandsontable()` for me